# SignalR + Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sending'

Tags: signalr.client

I was previously using an older ver of the signalR.js and everything is fine except it is intermittently causing my page to hang therefore I want to test it out with a newer ver from downloaded from the SignalR github site.

I tried following the client side example of SignalR but I get this error when inspecting element in chrome,

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'sending'. Anyone came across this error?

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>    
  <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"> </script>

        var hub = $.connection.testHub;
        hub.showMessage = function() {
                    $("#inboxcount").show();
                };

        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function() {
                hub.subscribe($('#<%= hdnUserId.ClientID %>').val());
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("Could not Connect!");
            });
```

TestHub.cs:

```
using System.Threading;

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test Hub used to demonstrate the key concepts of SignalR
    /// </summary>
    [SignalR.Hubs.HubName("testHub")]
    public class TestHub : SignalR.Hubs.Hub
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Broadcast the message to all clients
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">message to be broadcasted</param>
        public void Broadcast(string message)
        {
            this.Clients.showMessage(message);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a string with the formate, Hello [current user name]
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string SayHello()
        {
            //Context property can be used to retreive HTTP attributes like User
            return "Hello " + Context.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Simulates a long running process that updates its progress
        /// </summary>
        public void LongRunningMethod()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Caller.showMessage("25% Completed");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Caller.showMessage("50% Completed");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Caller.showMessage("75% Completed");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Caller.showMessage("Done");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subscribe to a given message category
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="category">the category to subscribe</param>
        public void Subscribe(string category)
        {
            //Add current connection to a connection group with the name 'category'
            this.AddToGroup(category);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Publish a message to the given mmessage category
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="category">the category to send the message</param>
        /// <param name="message">the message to be sent</param>
        public void Publish(string category, string message)
        {
            //Broadcast the message to all connections registered under the group 'category'
            this.Clients[category].showMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this all the code associated with your project?

Comment: Yes, that's all of it on SignalR with the TestHub.cs I just included, the other portion is for publishing the message but I think it's not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Well first off if you're using 1.0 alpha you have the wrong setup for your hubs.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/ for 1.0 alpha changes.  

For example hub.showMessage = fu.... would be hub.client.showMessage = fu....

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

instead of

```
 <script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

If that doesn't help, you should check if you don't have any old SignalR libraries in your project: So remove every SignalR dll, and add:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.AspNet
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Common

That did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Add server or client in hub call
hub.**server**.subscribe